# problem in getting the value from array in php

Tags: php, xml

i am using SimpleXML for very basic xml structure and after finding my specific value i just cannot get it out from the result. below is my code

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlStr);               

           foreach($values['type'] as $type)
           {                   
               $res = $xml->xpath("/domains/type[name='$type']/price"); 
               $price = (isset($res[0][0]))? $res[0][0] : 'US 0.0' ;
               $domain = $dname.$type;
               if( !checkdnsrr($domain) ){
                   $avails[$domain]['available'] = 'yes';
                   $avails[$domain]['price'] =  $price;
               }
               else
                   $avails[$domain] = 'no';
           }

            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($avails);
            echo '</pre>';
```

Below is the out put.

```
Array (
    [eee.com] => no
    [eee.net] => Array
        ( Blockquote
            [available] => yes
            [price] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => US $20
                )                 

         )
```

How can i get rid of that SimpleXMLElement Object and only have the value of it in price .?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$avails[$domain]['price']['0'] =  $price;
```

Should work.

EDIT: Unless, of course, there can be multiple prices, in which case, you want to do a `foreach` of some sorts.